# Using a held option

Tags: function-construction, options

Woud there be an elegant way to use a held option ?

For example if I need to pass by reference several variables but I don't always need all of them, it can be useful. For example if I want to append an element to a List/Association/Dataset.

I've managed to make something work but it's not very usable.

```
l = {};
ClearAll@ffff;
Options[ffff] = {"a" -> Hold[l]};
ffff[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := Function[Null, AppendTo[#, x], HoldFirst] @@ OptionValue["a"];
ffff[2]
l
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
l = {};
ClearAll@ffff;
Options[ffff] = {"a" :> l};
ffff[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  OptionValue[Automatic, Automatic, "a", Function[v, AppendTo[v, x], HoldFirst]]
```

That is, use `RuleDelayed` instead of `Rule` to define your held option, and then use extended syntax of `OptionValue`.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this fourth argument of OptionValue.

Answer (score 3):

As an improvement to Leonid's answer I've added a helper function, to avoid the Function syntax everytime.

```
l={};
ClearAll@ffff;
Options[ffff]={"a":>l};
heldOptionAppendTo[x_]:=Function[{v},AppendTo[v,x],HoldFirst];
ffff[x_,OptionsPattern[]]:=OptionValue[Automatic,Automatic,"a",heldOptionAppendTo[x]]
```

Some other similar useful functions. The great thing about Leonid's method and the OptionValue fourth argument is that we truly have access to the optional variable without an evaluation leak.

```
heldOptionSetKey[key_,value_]:=Function[{v},v[key]=value,HoldFirst];
heldOptionSetPart[part__,value_]:=Function[{v},v[[part]]=value,HoldFirst];
heldOptionIncrement[]:=Function[{v},v++,HoldFirst];
```